# Efficient way to add values from multiple struct

Tags: rust

Is there an efficient way of adding together the values of fields from multiple struct together?

I am learning Rust and trying to explore different methods and ways to get more efficient or more elegant code.

An easy method would be with the code as followed but is there maybe a better way? Using maybe a more in-depth use of iterators and its `.map()` method? I have tried using it but to not avail.

```rust
fn create_bloc(name: String, value: u32) -> ControlBloc {
    ControlBloc { name, value }
}

fn main() {
    let vec_bloc = vec![
        create_bloc(String::from("b1"), 1),
        create_bloc(String::from("b2"), 2),
        create_bloc(String::from("b3"), 3),
        create_bloc(String::from("b4"), 4),
        create_bloc(String::from("b5"), 5),
    ];

    let mut count = 0;

    for ele in vec_bloc.iter() {
        count += ele.value;
    }

    println!("Count = {}", count);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific goal? If not, this may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: So many things I could point you to. [`.iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) (which you can use because of auto-dereferencing). [`.sum()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum). The turbofish. Rustfmt. The [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7e73856a6564bf5a86c9c956392f5d5f). Hf learning Rust.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I suppose just trying something new, nothing specific in mind but something that I can expand if I want to modify the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more idiomatic way:

```rust
struct ControlBloc {
    name: String,
    value: i32,
}

impl ControlBloc {
    fn new(name: String, value: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            name,
            value,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec_bloc = vec![
        ControlBloc::new(String::from("b1"), 1),
        ControlBloc::new(String::from("b2"), 2),
        ControlBloc::new(String::from("b3"), 3),
        ControlBloc::new(String::from("b4"), 4),
        ControlBloc::new(String::from("b5"), 5),
    ];

    let count = vec_bloc.iter().fold(0, |acc, x| acc + x.value);
    println!("Count = {}", count);
}
```

As others have said, there's obviously a number of concepts you haven't come across yet which you should learn. I'd start with [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/)!

Comment: Thank you this looks really cool, there is indeed a lot of iter functions i need to look at

Comment: It can be confusing at first but iteration in Rust makes sense before long. `Iterator` is a trait which means something can be iterated over, so that type would have to hold some state, like what point in the iteration we're at. So there's a distinction between something like a `Vec` and an actual type which implements `Iterator`. `IntoIterator` is a trait allowing a type to be de-sugared into an `impl Iterator` when used in a `for` loop.

Comment: I agree this is idiomatic, but is there any way to do something similar to C++ aggregate initialization for structs in Rust?  This is just a flip from a free function to an `impl` one (which again, I agree is normal) for each element.

Comment: I would prefer `vec_bloc.iter().map(|x| x.value).sum::<i32>()`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Are you thinking of something like `ControlBloc { name: "b1".into(), value: 1 }`?